# PHP - Forcing an MP3 file download

Tags: php, download, header, readfile

So, I need a little help here. I have a site which hosts some mp3s. When users click on the download url, it links directly to a file called downloadmp3.php, which goes 2 parameters in the url...the php file is included below, and it's basically supposed to FORCE the user to save the mp3. (not play it in the browser or anything).

That doesnt happen. Instead, it seems like the file is WRITTEN out in ascii to the browser. It seems like it's the actual mp3 file written out.

Here is my downloadmp3.php file...please, what's wrong in this code.
It works on my local LAMP (Bitnami Wampstack on windows)....that is, on my local testing environment, it sends the file to my broswer, and I can save it. When I upload it to the real server, it basically writes out the mp3 file.

Here is the culprit file, downloadmp3.php...please help

```
<?php
include 'ngp.php';
$file = $_GET['songurl'];
$songid = $_GET['songid'];
increasedownloadcount($songid);
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

By the way, this site only hosts mp3s - no other audio or file format. So, this downloadmp3.php script should ideally ask the user where they want to save this file.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Are you getting these different results (forced download from localhost and written out from server) in the same browser? If different browsers, what they are?

Comment: I am working both in Chrome and Firefox, and both of them 'spit' out the same read-out mp3 file. pls remember that it gives me the file on my local machine. It's from the real web host that it gives the ascii soup.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `filename` should be in quotes:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the content-type value to text/plain. With this browser wont recognize it and wont play the file. Instead it will download the file at clients machine.

Comment: Do you actually use the url for that file exists check or is it the file system path. Changing the content-type to text/plain and using the path of mp3 file to file system path worked well for me. I tried the code without modification, just passing the fileur to filesystem relative path

Comment: I dont think finding the file is the problem. The code works properly on my local server. On the real web host it finds the file too, just that it doesnt return it as an mp3 file, but as a 'printed out mp3 file in text form' it seems.

Comment: Still I would recommend using the file system paths and not the URLs. It should fix your problem and is also good because the urls would be overhead rather than accessing them locally. Further more, if urls are user provided, in case of rubbish url it could slowdown the performance of your server leading to slowloris attack effect.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is too many headers. I am sure they do SOMETHING... but this code works.

This code works with MP3 files.... downloads  to a file. Plays without a problem.

```
if(isset($_GET['file'])){
    $file = $_GET['file'];
    header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file.'"');
    readfile('path/to/your/'.$file);
    exit();
}
```

You can access it with ajax call, or this:
`<a id="dl_link" href="download.php?file=<>file-you-wish-to-download<>" target="_blank">Download this file</a>`

Hopefully this is of some use